# Cannot redirect to an empty URL. in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse->setTargetUrl() when access the front page

Tags: 8

After clearing the cache, the front page becomes inaccessible. When I visit it, I see this error message.

> Cannot redirect to an empty URL. in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse->setTargetUrl() (line 86 of vendor/symfony/http-foundation/RedirectResponse.php).

Why does it happen?

Here is another update, after I open full backtrace, I find the related code all related to the drupal core, I find the code is all related to drupal core.

> Drupal\Component\HttpFoundation\SecuredRedirectResponse->setTargetUrl('') (Line: 39)
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse->__construct('', 301, Array) (Line: 26)
> Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse->__construct('', 301) (Line: 128)
> Drupal\redirect\EventSubscriber\RouteNormalizerRequestSubscriber->onKernelRequestRedirect(Object, 'kernel.request', Object)
> call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.request', Object) (Line: 111)
> Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object) (Line: 127)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
> Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Comment: Hi Tony, Welcome to Drupal Stack Exchange. Did you try clearing cache through Drush and checked it again ? Have you made any changes recently. Did you Check logs ? Without more details we can not provide any suggestions.

Comment: Hi, I have already run cron job and clear cache via Drush, but the problem still exist, I just try to run clear cache in UI and this error appear, after that, the front page become inaccessible.

Comment: I find the log will show below error.
invalidArgumentException: Cannot redirect to an empty URL. in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse->setTargetUrl() (line 86 of /var/www/drupal8/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/RedirectResponse.php).

Comment: One more thing, before I use the clean the cache, I am using the csv_import to import content and it encounter gateway timeout. Thank you

Comment: There are two problems here. (1) Someone is trying to create a RedirectResponse with an empty URL. (2) Someone puts a RedirectResponse in code which is cached. Not a good idea because then it gets only executed after a cache clear, which helps in this case because (1) only happens after a cache clear. To solve the problem you need more debugging info. What was the last step before the error occurred? If you can't reproduce the error then try to find the code responsible in a full error message with backtrace information: */admin/config/development/logging*

Answer (score 1):

> Here is another update, after I open full backtrace, I find the
> related code all related to the drupal core, I find the code is all
> related to drupal core.

It's not core. This is the last line before the response object is constructed.

> Drupal\redirect\EventSubscriber\RouteNormalizerRequestSubscriber->onKernelRequestRedirect(Object,
> 'kernel.request', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object,
> 'kernel.request', Object) (Line: 111)

This is in the namespace of the contrib module Redirect, which by the way is using a cacheable redirect response in an event subscriber, so my comment about not using RedirectResponse in cacheable code doesn't apply here.

Try to disable *Enforce clean and canonical URLs* in the module's settings. If this issue is specific to a route you can disable it in the route definition by setting a default `_disable_route_normalizer: TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I will try to work on it.